# Mixing existing Play static routes with new 'compile-time' dependency-injected controller instances

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have an existing application that has a bunch of pre-2.4 static object-style controllers that I don't want to touch at this point.

Meanwhile, I want to add some new functionality and controllers, but in new code I want to use the paradigm which the Play-people call 'compile-time' injection.

To that effect I have setup some basic wiring as per [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection):

```
class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    Logger.info("initializing the application in play 2.4-style")
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  lazy val router: play.api.routing.Router = ???
  lazy val someNewController = new SomeNewController(new SomeComponent())

}
```

The problem is with configuring/implementing the router.

I'd like it to take all the generated routes (from the pre-existing routes file) and add the new route handled by `SomeNewController`.

It is my understanding that I can't add `SomeNewController` to the routes file with @syntax because that assumes that I'll be using what Play calls 'runtime DI' using Guice, which I don't want to do.

**How do I keep my existing routes and add the new one for the `someNewController` instance, essentially merging them?**

I guess I have to instantiate a `play.api.routing.Router` and populate it with the routes that live in the generated `router.Routes` object, and adding an entry for SomeNewController, but the API is not immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silence (in terms of responses) indicates what I already feared: I was out on a limb.

While mixing and matching the routes may be possible theoretically, it would require some voodoo so deeply connected with the intricacies of Play that I wouldn't recommend it to anyone.

What I have done now, is just to migrate all my controllers and their collaborators to 'compile-time DI'. This was quite a big undertaking and the fact that I was forced to do it is indicative of the practicality of the upgrade-paths provided by Play.